# Understanding Hybridisation in Cyclic Compounds

Tags: aromatic-compounds, hybridization, heterocyclic-compounds

I had a doubt while solving this problem.

At first glance of these compounds, I felt that **all of them have sp3 hybridisation (for nitrogen), since all of them had 3 bonded pairs and 1 lone pair around the nitrogen atom**.

But then I saw in a website **that both 2 and 3 have sp2 hybridisation. Can you explain why this occurs?**[image]

Comment: Only (3) - it's conjugated, 2 is not.

Answer (score 1):

The design of the question offers you four choices where choice **4** states nitrogen in both case **2** and **3** (formally) were $\text{sp}^2$ hybridized.

Case **3** however differs from case **1** and **2** by that the lone electron pair of nitrogen no longer is isolated (as in open chain/alkyl amines), but is in conjugation with both $\ce{C=C}$ double bonds.  Because the skeleton is cyclic, of about planar geometry, and the total of participating $\pi$ electrons equals to 6, pyrrole is an electron rich Hückel aromatic system ($4n + 2$, here with $n = 1$).  Thus, **3** it is the only example among the structures displayed where nitrogen is $\text{sp}^2$ hybridized.*  Because the orientation of the lone orbital of nitrogen affects the chemistry (e.g., $\text{p}K_a$), I recommend an additional reading about e.g., imidazole:

[image]

(image credit to [chem.libretexts.org](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Organic_Chemistry_(Morsch_et_al.)/15%3A_Benzene_and_Aromaticity/15.05%3A_Aromatic_Heterocycles-_Pyridine_and_Pyrrole))

* Actually, atoms do not hybridize.  Hybridization is one of the *mathematical* concepts in chemistry, here: how to mix atomic orbitals to yield molecular orbitals of certain shape.

Answer (score 0):

Only option three would have $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridization for nitrogen as it’s Nitrogen has π-bond in conjugation. Therefore the lone pair of nitrogen is delocalized thus in the newly formed resonating structure Nitrogen does not have 1 lone pair and 3 $\sigma$-bonds but 3 $\sigma$-bonds and one π-bond… Giving $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridization.